# Pandas Styling with Conditional Rules

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I was trying to style a Pandas Dataframe using 2 different columns.
I was successful as long as the conditional was about the column itself, however when it depends on another one, I was unable to get the desired results.

I want to color the cell in "Date II" if "Date I" is in the past.

```
def date_pii(row):
        ret = ["" for _ in row.index]
        print(row['Date PI'])
        if row['Date PI'] < datetime.now():
            ret[row.index.get_loc("Date PII")] = "background-color: red"
            return ret

styler = df3.style \
        .applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: %s' % 'red' if x <= datetime.now() else '', subset=['Date PI']) \
        .applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: %s' % 'yellow' if x < datetime.now() + timedelta(days=30) else '',
                  subset=['Date PII']) \
        .applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: %s' % 'orange' if x <= datetime.now() else '', subset=['Date PII']) \
        .applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: %s' % 'grey' if pd.isnull(x) else '', subset=['Date PI'])\
        .applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: %s' % 'grey' if pd.isnull(x) else '', subset=['Date PII'])\
        .apply(date_pii, axis=1) ----> THIS IS THE ISSUE

styler.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Report Paris', index=False)
```

At runtime I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Function <function generate_report_all.<locals>.date_pii at 0x7fd3964d9160> returned the wrong shape.
Result has shape: (532,)
Expected shape:   (532, 10)
```

The dataframe looks like this:
[image: df3]

The first orange cell in "Date PII" is correct, however, the remaining ones (where PI is red) I would like them to become red as well.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you provide a sample input dataframe (a few representative rows of `df3`) and explain how you want it to be styled. It seems like there's a fair room for improvement in the styling overall and it would really help if we had an idea of what you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: @HenryEcker once again thank you for the help :)
Post edited!

Comment: What are the rules?

Comment: If "Date PII" within next 30 days --> "Date PII" style yellow ///
If "Date PII" in past & "Date PI" in future --> "Date PII" style orange ///
If "Date PI" in past --> "Date PII" and "Date PI" style red ///
If "Date PII" empty --> "Date PII" style grey ///
If "Date PI" empty --> "Date PI" style grey

Comment: "Date PI" should not be yellow. It becomes red once in the past.
"Date PII" goes from yellow (closing to 30 days), orange if in the past, and red if "Date PI" is in the past. The grey is for null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general approach to this type of problem is to pass the specified columns as a `subset` to [`Styler.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html). This allows us to create styles at the DataFrame level and use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) indexing to build out the styles based on conditions. The other major benefit is that rather than chaining we can use the extra space to provide documentation and also reduce the overhead of all of those lambda:

```
def style_dates(subset_df):
    # Empty Styles
    style_df = pd.DataFrame(
        '', index=subset_df.index, columns=subset_df.columns
    )
    # Today's Date
    today = pd.Timestamp.now().normalize()
    # Date PII is within 30 days from today
    style_df.loc[
        subset_df['Date PII'].le(today + pd.Timedelta(days=30)),
        'Date PII'
    ] = 'background-color: yellow'

    # Date PI is before today
    style_df.loc[
        subset_df['Date PI'].lt(today),
        ['Date PI', 'Date PII']
    ] = 'background-color: red'

    # Date PII is before today and Date PI is after Today
    style_df.loc[
        subset_df['Date PII'].lt(today) & subset_df['Date PI'].gt(today),
        'Date PII'
    ] = 'background-color: orange'

    # Either is NaN
    style_df[subset_df.isna()] = 'background-color: gray'
    return style_df


styler = df3.style.apply(
    style_dates, axis=None, subset=['Date PII', 'Date PI']
).format(
    # Optional Explicit Date Format
    formatter='{:%Y-%m-%d}', na_rep='NaT', subset=['Date PII', 'Date PI']
)
```

[image: styled DataFrame]

---

Setup DataFrame randomly generated always relative to the current date (styles will be consistent while dates will not be):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import Generator, MT19937

norm_today = pd.Timestamp.now().normalize()
rng = Generator(MT19937(1023))


def md(lower_bound, upper_bound, rng_=rng):
    return pd.Timedelta(days=rng_.integers(lower_bound, upper_bound))


df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Desc': [
        'PII within 30 days',  # PII yellow
        'PII in past and PI in future',  # PII orange
        'PI past',  # Both red
        'PI empty',  # grey
        'PII empty',  # grey
        'PII in future but not within 30 days'  # No Styles
    ],
    'Date PII': [norm_today + md(1, 10), norm_today - md(1, 10),
                 norm_today, norm_today, np.nan,
                 norm_today + md(40, 50)],
    'Date PI': [norm_today, norm_today + md(1, 10),
                norm_today - md(1, 10), np.nan, norm_today,
                norm_today]
})
```

| Desc | Date PII | Date PI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PII within 30 days | 2021-11-06 00:00:00 | 2021-11-03 00:00:00 |
| PII in past and PI in future | 2021-10-31 00:00:00 | 2021-11-11 00:00:00 |
| PI past | 2021-11-03 00:00:00 | 2021-11-01 00:00:00 |
| PI empty | 2021-11-03 00:00:00 | NaT |
| PII empty | NaT | 2021-11-03 00:00:00 |
| PII in future but not within 30 days | 2021-12-19 00:00:00 | 2021-11-03 00:00:00 |

Answer (score 1):

While @HenryEcker solution works at the DataFrame level (notice his use of the `axis=None` keyword argument) there are times when a simpler approach might be warranted.

Since your conditions are entirely row dependent you can use apply with `axis=1` and attach a function that calculates based on the columns values in each row.

For example:

```
df = DataFrame([[1,2,3],[3,2,1]], index=["i", "j"], columns=["A", "B", "C"])

   A   B   C
i  1   2   3
j  3   2   1
```

Suppose we want to highlight column `C` if it is less than column `A`:

```
def highlight(s):
    if s["C"] < s["A"]
        return ["", "color: red;"]
    return ["", ""]

df.style.apply(highlight, subset=["A", "C"], axis=1)
```

[image]